# Are there any limits on the types in the typecast operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was wondering if anyone knows what the limits are on the conversion/typecast operator?

So, for example, I can have the following override operators:

```
class Test {
    operator int() { return 0; };
    operator int*() { return nullptr; };
}
```

For a regular function, I could also have a pointer to array type. E.g.

```
int (*MyFunc())[4] { return nullptr; };
```

However, I don't know how to do the same for the conversion operator (or if it is even legal to do so). I have tried a few different variations and VS2010 and none work. (Such as:)

```
operator int (*())[4] { return nullptr; };
operator int(*)[4]() { return nullptr; };
```

I'm not sure if this is a limitation in VS2010 or if there is a general limit on the types that can be used in the conversion operator. I tried looking for the standard online with no luck. Does anyone know? Before anyone asks "why would you even want to do that", it's for auto-generated code. Although I don't anticipate getting pointer to array input, I would like to be able to produce the code if it is legal in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are restrictions. The limitation you've hit with arrays is due to the language grammar. The grammar specification for a conversion operator (and kin) is as follows:

```
§12.3.2
conversion-function-id:
    operator conversion-type-id
conversion-type-id:
    type-specifier-seq conversion-declarator[opt]
conversion-declarator:
    ptr-operator conversion-declarator[opt]

§7.1.6
type-specifier:
    trailing-type-specifier
    class-specifier
    enum-specifier
trailing-type-specifier:
    simple-type-specifier
    elaborated-type-specifier
    typename-specifier
    cv-qualifier
type-specifier-seq:
    type-specifier attribute-specifier-seq[opt]
    type-specifier type-specifier-seq
trailing-type-specifier-seq:
    trailing-type-specifier attribute-specifier-seq[opt]
    trailing-type-specifier trailing-type-specifier-seq
```

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to look at all those, but you can't specify an array as the type directly. (It is only specified in *declarations*.) Luckily, though, a typedef-name is allowed (through the typename-specifier), and because a typedef is a kind of declaration, arrays work there:

```
struct Test {
    typedef int operator_type[4];

    operator operator_type*() { return nullptr; };
};
```

Long story short, use a typedef and you can use whatever type you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. That's answered my question exactly.

Answer (score 6):

You should mostly use `typedef` in hard constructs, also you got the syntax wrong ,

`operator Type () {}`

I'm gonna use `typedef`s though

```
typedef int (*foo())[4];
typedef int(*bar)[4];
```

using the typedef

`operator  foo() { return nullptr; }` // here you're trying to convert `nullptr` to a **"function"** which returns pointer to array of 4 `int`'s , which is obviously wrong.

`operator  bar() { return nullptr; }` //your second conversion is valid though, since you're converting `nullptr` to **pointer** to array of 4 `int`s

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid using typedef but I guess there's no choice.